# invoke EJB method with http request

Tags: http, jboss, ejb

If I have a stateless bean in jboss 4, which annotations should I add so that I can call method A via http request?

I found @WebService annotation for bean class, but what should be done for method?

Comment: Did you check @WebMethod annotation ?

Comment: Thanks, i've checked  it - but how can I specify url for  the method?
    @ Stateless

    @ WebService(name = "AuctionService", serviceName = "AuctionService")

public class AuctionService implements AuctionServiceRemote

{

   @ WebMethod

   public boolean login(String username, String password)

   {

      Identity.instance().setUsername(username);

      Identity.instance().setPassword(password);

      Identity.instance().login();

      return Identity.instance().isLoggedIn();

   }


   // snip

}
What URL should I write to call the method?